# No output device for bluetooth earbuds (Galaxy Buds+)

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth

The earbuds are paired and connected and "recognized" as an audio device but they do not appear as an output device in sound settings:

[Sound Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxJcX.png)

[Bluetooth Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9FNS.png)